# TrueCrypt & upgrading your hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, truecrypt

I currently use TrueCrypt to encrypt the hard drive in a Win7 laptop (everything in a single partition).  I am looking to upgrade the hard drive to a model with significantly more storage capacity.  I've had a look through the documentation but I couldn't see anything about this particular scenario.

I assume I need to do something like the following:

1. Remove the encryption from the existing drive.
2. Clone the existing drive image onto the new hard drive.
3. Physically install the new drive into the laptop.
4. Resize the single partition to use all the space in the new drive.
5. Encrypt all of the new bigger drive with TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

1. boot into windows PE, unlock drive 0 using truecrypt, create partition on new drive (diskpart select disk 1, create part, format quick fs=ntfs, assign letter=D)that is the full size.
2. Use a tool like imagex that is built for windows 7 to copy all the files from one drive to another? ("imagex /capture c: d:\BigBackup.wim "backup" /verify", followed by a "imagex /apply d:\BigBackup.wim 1 d: /verify")
3. Imagex is file based, not sector based, so you can copy files to different sized partitions.
4. Swap in the new drive, and boot from it
5. Encrypt new drive with truecrypt?

That way, your orignal disk stays encrypted.  You can pop it back in if something goes wrong, and you don't have to worry about all your data sitting there in the clear..